# How to import from nested module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, jspm

I have a Typescript library I've written which is being emitted as follows. I'm not sure how to import from this module, though.

**node_modules/my-module/dist/index.js** (partial)

```
define("services/UserService", ["require", "exports", ..., "services/BaseService"], function (require, exports, ..., BaseService_31) {
    "use strict";
    var UserService = (function (_super) {
        // ... stuff here ...

        return UserService;
    }(BaseService_31.BaseService));
    exports.UserService = UserService;
});
```

I've installed this package with `npm` and configured JSPM as follows:

**config.js** (partial)

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "none",
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "npm-ext:*": "node_modules/*"
  },
  map: {
    ...
    "my-module": "npm-ext:my-module/dist/index.js",
    ...
  }
});
```

I was expecting to be able to import this class as follows...

```
import {UserService} from "my-module/services/UserService";
```

I expected SystemJS to resolve the path to `my-module` and then locate the `services/UserService` module, and grab the single export `UserService`. But in the Chrome Console I see this is the path which is being loaded:

```
node_modules/my-module/dist/index.js/models/UserService.js
```

What's the correct way to import a module such as this?

*Bonus:* how can I get around including the full path to `index.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Your library code was emitted using named define

```
define("services/UserService",
```

And it looks like there are several such modules defined in the index.js file, that is, index.js is a bundle.

The only way to import such module using SystemJS is

```
import {UserService} from "services/UserService";
```

That is, imported module name must match exactly the name given to `define`. In your case, the location of the file does not affect module name in any way.

Now, SystemJS has to be configured to load library file, `node_modules/my-module/dist/index.js`, when it sees that import. For bundles, the preferred way to to it is via [bundles config](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#bundle):

```
  bundles: {
    "npm-ext:my-module/dist/index.js": ["services/UserService.js"]
  }
```

Module name here, `services/UserService.js`, must have `.js` extension because it must match imported module name after `defaultJSExtesions:true` is applied.

If you want the module to be imported as `my-module/services/UserService.js`, then you need to make sure it is registered with that name. The easiest way is to have corresponding source file structure when compiling the library - that is, have UserService.ts in `my-module/services` folder.

You can find more information about named define in [SystemJS module format docs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#amd), which says in particular

> - Named defines are supported and will write directly into the loader registry.
> - A single named define will write into the loader registry but also be treated as the value of the module loaded if the names do not match. This enables loading a module containing define('jquery', ....

**P.S.** Your browser tries to load

```
node_modules/my-module/dist/index.js/models/UserService.js
```

where does `models` come from?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to configure my TS build to create "normal" modules so I can import with `my-module/services/UserService`? Also, "models" was probably a typo, will confirm.

Comment: The only way I know is by having rigid layout for source files. Suppose you have src/my-module/service folder with UserService.ts and BaseService.ts. Also suppose that src and dist are at the top level. To generate 'normal' modules, use `"rootDir": "src", "outDir": "dist"` in tsconfig.json. Note that each module will be in separate file. To generate a bundle, replace `outDir` with `"outFile": "dist/index.js"`. In both cases, you can import with `from 'my-module/services/UserService'`.